# How do I change the file that the XSLT template is using in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, ide

I have an XSLT file and the first time I ran it, it asked me for an XML file. How do I get it to let go of that setting and let me choose a new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the XSL file, then go to the Properties window (`'View->Properties Window'`/`F4`). The XML file to be tranformed is the `Input` field in that window.